# Store JSON response value in property

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm making an api call and assigned a property to the result. I'm then trying to use this property to modify the data but I get an undefined error:

This is my class:

```
@Injectable()
export class DisplayService {
    screens: Array<any>;

    constructor(public http: Http){

    }

    getDisplays() {
        var path = 'http://localhost:8000/getscreens';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: path,
            success: function(data){
                this.screens = data.screens;
            }
        });
        console.log(this.screens);
    }
}
```

`data.screens` is working as expected; however, when I `console.log` `this.screens` I get `undefined`. How can I store the response for later use?

Comment: May I ask why are you using jQuery for your call? Why don't you use `Http` (it's even in your service constructor)?

Comment: @EricMartinez I am I just changed it to make the question more understandable since I wasn't sure how many people are familiar with `Http`

Answer (score 0):

Just looks like scope issue... Try:

```
@Injectable()
export class DisplayService {
    screens: Array<any>;

    constructor(public http: Http){

    }

    getDisplays() {
        var path = 'http://localhost:8000/getscreens';
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: path,
            success: function(data){
                that.screens = data.screens;
            }
        });
        console.log(this.screens);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought that was the issue but sadly its not

Comment: lol duh... ajax is well, asynch... the console.log is going to run before the success fires... totally missed that